# Can't get height-attribute in Bootstrap 4 alpha to work

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-4

I'm learning Bootstrap, and I can't get the height attribute in v4 (e.g.: "row h-25") to work.

I've tried to add another CSS which sets the height of "container-fluid" as well as html and body to 100%, which someone proposed as a solution in another answer. Still doesn't work, I'm afraid. I'm using Visual Studio, and when I open "NuGet - Solution", it says that the bootstrap version is 'v4.0.0-alpha'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #e7fdd6">
        <div class="row h-25" style="background-color: #eee">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><p>Customer</p><!-- These are just rough drafts while I learn the grid system. --></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><p>Power</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><p>Panels</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><p>Projects</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row h-25" style="background-color: #eee">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><p>Customer-slider</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><p>Power amount</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><p>Panels</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><p>Projects-slider</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row h-25">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><img src="Content/picture.jpg" alt="Park" align="middle" /> <!-- Bilde --></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row h-25">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6-col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!-- Graph 1 --></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs"><!-- Graph 2 --></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.css:

```
.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 alpha works well with h-25 class.You have to set the height for the parent element i.e.,container-fluid in px,rem or em.Do not add parent height in percentage.

```
.container-fluid {
    min-height: 200px ;
}
```

Best practise is to add styles to custom class in the parent element rather than applying the styles for bootstrap core classes.

Comment: This was the issue, height had to be set for the container, and not just min-height. Thanks, and thanks to Klooven for the help too.

But what seemed like the beauty of Bootstrap was that I could program for different device sizes real easily (with xs, sm, etc), but if I have to set the exact pixel height, that kind of ruins that.  Best practice with this?

Answer (score 0):

The `h-` (like `h-25`) classes were introduced in Bootstrap Alpha v6, so you need to upgrade your Bootstrap version to use these.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your NuGet reference is an older alpha version of Bootstrap 4. The [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap/absoluteLatest), as of right now, is 4.0.0-beta2.

In the VS NuGet Package Manager (right-click the solution and choose "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..."), you should see that there are updates to the package. If not, make sure the "Include prerelease" checkbox is checked.